# I created new Azure App but it keep showing error message Need admin approval

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory

I created a new app in azure but when users try to log in they keep getting message admin approval required

[image: Admin Consent]

[image: Config]

[image: Permissions]

I have changed to single tenant still same issue. as far i know from microsoft that if you only allow basic info you dont need to approve the app.

[image: Account type settings]

These are the steps I've taken to create an app.

1. Create new app called "NameOfYourApp"
2. Add following URLs

   - https://YourEnvironment/MicrosoftLoginConnector/Callback.aspx
   - https://YourEnvironment/NameOfYourApp/Callback.aspx
3. - Enable in Windows Azure Active Directory the access to 2 permissions Read all users' basic profiles and Sign in and read user profile.
   - Add Dynamics CRM Online and enable the access to 1 permission: Access Dynamics 365 as organization users.
4. Generated a Client Secret key

Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to approve Grant admin consent

[image]

Comment: Can you please check you are the redirect URL in OAuth token and did you map with any of your web page?

Comment: Can you please let me know what you mean by OAuth token.

Comment: Please let me know how are you authenticating with your Application.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, your app is a multi-tenant app, I suppose you use a user account in a different tenant to login the app, if so, you will get the error because of the setting in `Azure Active Directory` -> `Enterprise applications` -> `User settings`.

[image]

If the option is set to `No`, the normal user will not have the permission to consent the app from another different tenant, even if the API permission you request does not need admin consent. I can also reproduce your issue.

[image]

So to solve the issue, you have the options below.

1.Set the `Users can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf` to `Yes`, after some delay, the normal user will be able to consent the app by himself.

2.Let the admin of another tenant to login the app and consent for it, or hit the [`tenant-wide admin consent URL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#construct-the-url-for-granting-tenant-wide-admin-consent) - `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id}`, login and consent for the app.

Comment: I run this https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id} and accepted "Permissions requested Accept for your organisation"

Comment: @maj You use a normal user in the same tenant of your app to login? Please show your request url used to login.

Comment: When click on Accept I get redirect to new url with following error "The page cannot be found. Please make sure you typed the URL correctly. "

Comment: "Set the Users can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf to Yes, after some delay, the normal user will be able to consent the app by himself." 

I did set this up yesterday and then try to use it but nothing happen. Do I need to wait for system to take effected before try it again

Comment: @maj Please wait, first, could you tell me if the user account is in the same tenant of the App? If yes, is it a work account (i.e. xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com) or personal account (e.g. xxx@outlook.com)? And please show your request URL used to login in the question?

Comment: User account is in the same tenant as the app. User is using its company email. Company domain existed in Tenant.

Comment: @maj Which flow do you use to login? Could you show the request url? Then I can test for you.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand your question. We are using wwwdev.customdomain.co.uk/home.aspx

Comment: After runnng "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id}" We dont get approve admin message but showing different error, it might be redirect url error.

Comment: @maj No need to use the admin consent url, because the user is in the same tenant, the problem is you don’t understand what I am asking, without the necessary information, I could not test it and find the solution for you.